# SSRS (SQL Server 2008 R2) Report Builder Using =First function

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am writing a simple report in SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder (SSRS).

I want to get a phone number using this expression:

```
=First(Fields!PHONE1.Value, "TWO")
```

and it is returning the exact phone number (no error). Phone number length is 14 characters, but I wanted to get only first 10 digits/characters.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=LEFT(First(Fields!PHONE1.Value, "TWO"),10)
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would `SELECT left([PHONE1],10)` in my SQL query.